# Styling a category link

Tags: php, themes

I am still learning but I wasnt able to style a category link. I was able to create the following so only 1 category link is displayed. But I was unsure how I can modify this so I can add a class and style it. Is anyone able to help?

```
            <?php 
             // category link   
$categories = get_the_category();
        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) 
      ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
      }
    // category link
         ?>
```

Comment: You've got HTML right there `<a href="`. Just add a class to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it with your code, using the category name as the class name:

```
<?php 
             // category link   
$categories = get_the_category();
        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
echo '<a class="' .esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) 
      ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
      }
    // category link
         ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was resolved using the above answer. Adding <a class